# Recruiter claims to have gotten my email address from Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, support, email

**Update:** This was five years ago. I've since revised my judgement of Stack Exchange's ethics downward, roughly to zero.

I just received an email with an unsolicited job offer from somebody who ***claims*** to have found me on Stack Overflow. It was addressed to "Ed", a name I use nowhere but Stack Overflow (it's [not my real name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edward_Plunkett,_18th_Baron_of_Dunsany)), and she says she's looking for a .NET developer, which I am.

So "random spam sent to 1,000,000 random people" is obviously a possibility, but it seems to me it's an unlikely one. Stack Overflow is the only place I know of where the name "Ed" is associated with my [Gmail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gmail) address and my profession. Anybody can say "Stack Overflow" in an email; putting that together with those two other pieces of information is curious.

She claims to be recruiting for a business called (seriously) "pureromance.com". The email seems to suggest that they sell sex toys or something related; I'm not going to click the link at work to find out the exact details.

UPDATE: Checked them out. It's not a legitimate business. It's a multi-level marketing deal where you pay them for the privilege of trying to sell their sex toys to your friends. They make the usual preposterous promises, with a thick layer of sex positive female empowerment rhetoric spackled on top.

I don't use Stack Overflow Jobs. I don't have a developer CV on Stack Overflow. These days I'm not contacting anybody anywhere about jobs (nor sex toys (NO NO IT"S FOR A FRIEND!!!)), and I've never gone looking for jobs under an assumed name anyhow. I often get emails from recruiters I've dealt with in the past, but they use my real name.

Is there any legitimate way a spammer could get my email address from Stack Overflow? I've got nothing about Stack Overflow on my [LinkedIn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LinkedIn) or [GitHub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitHub) profiles.

It seems very much out of character for Stack Overflow to be handing out users' email addresses, even to reputable businesses. Or are recruiters regarded as an exception? If it is Stack Overflow, I'm disappointed, and I'd like to find the profile setting to prevent this from happening again.

But it seems really far-fetched that Stack Overflow is knowingly handing out my email address to anybody without explicit permission.

## UPDATE

@Carpetsmoker links to the [Stack Overflow  Privacy Policy](https://stackexchange.com/legal/privacy-policy), which says just what you and I both assumed it would:

> "It's hard to imagine that we would ever consider collecting, let alone sharing, sensitive information with a non-agent third party, but if such a day should come, we will first give you the opportunity to explicitly consent (opt-in) to such disclosure or to any use of the information for a purpose other than the one for which it was originally collected or previously authorized."

## UPDATE 2

I just remembered I briefly corresponded a few months ago, using that same email address, with a Stack Overflow user.

It is a very strange world we live in.

## Update 3

Two days later, on a Saturday, this Kathryn Pravel character contacted me again:

> I wanted to follow up on my previous note about the Sr .Net role at Pure Romance. Any questions I can answer for you?
>
> [blah blah blah blah]

I changed my "send as" name in gmail to a new unused pseudonym and replied:

> Yeah, I've got a question you can answer:
>
> Where did you get my contact information, and why are you bothering me?
>
> Just curious. That name isn't associated publicly with that email address on Github or Stack Overflow.

No reply. I marked her as spam and that's the end of it.

Comment: Note that recruiters aren't swearing an oath to tell the truth, the whole truth, and nothing but the truth when talking with you.  Just because they say they got their email from somewhere doesn't necessarily mean that's true; in fact they're very much incentivised to not tell the truth about where they got your email from.  All that said, you should check what your privacy settings are for the info on your profile.

Comment: @Servy As I made clear, SO is the only place I know of where the name "Ed" is associated with my gmail address and my profession. But thanks for letting me know I didn't make it clear enough. Will fix. Unfortunately the meaning of "somebody who **claims** to have found me on StackOverflow" can't be made any clearer than it is.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Did you used your email for your GitHub profile and if yes, do you have a repository, which uses git on GitHub?

Comment: @Rizier123 I just looked and couldn't find any way to get to a GitHub profile from SO, even with a decent amount of Googling.

Comment: @Rizier123 Yes. It's not shown publicly there either, and it seems more likely that somebody who had gotten it from them would be using that fake name instead of this one. Of course maybe this recruiter just calls everybody "Ed" -- anything is possible. Also, I just searched and my email address and this name appear nowhere in any repository I'm involved with on GH.

Comment: From the [Privacy policy](http://stackexchange.com/legal/privacy-policy): *"It’s hard to imagine that we would ever consider collecting, let alone sharing, sensitive information with a non-agent third party, but if such a day should come, we will first give you the opportunity to explicitly consent (opt-in) to such disclosure or to any use of the information for a purpose other than the one for which it was originally collected or previously authorized."* It's possible (but unlikely) that a nefarious or disgruntled SE employee *sold* you data. Unfortunately I've seen this happen up close :-(

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Thank you.

Comment: Related: ["Is my email address accessible?"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/293532/is-my-email-address-accessible) and ["Someone contacted me by email but my email is not public"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207872/someone-contacted-me-by-email-but-my-email-is-not-public) . People regularly write me and claim that they've gotten my email address from Stack Overflow, when the address they're using isn't the one I have attached to this profile but the one I have listed on my website or GitHub repositories.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker That last point is my concern.

Comment: Did you know that recruiters widely share information illegally and think it's hilarious? I know because more than one of them told me this between 2013 and now.

Comment: @Hack-R Doesn't surprise me a bit.

Comment: Recruiters (like most marketers) don't use information from "just one place". They have data-mining software that attempts to put everything together. This recruiter put a lot of information together, the only missing piece was your name, which they found on StackOverflow.

Comment: PureRomance is a valid company. The organisation I work with have done some dev work with them in past.

Comment: @DhruvJoshi It does appear to be a real company. Judging by [what it says on the recruiter's LinkedIn page](https://www.linkedin.com/in/kathryn-pravel-727b164), it sounds a bit MLMish/scammy. Not something I'd personally get involved with. Their recruiting practices are questionable, but this Kathryn Pravel seems to be a recent hire, and you can't condemn a whole program because of a single slip-up.

Comment: Brave New World, not a "strange world" at all. I only use public resources and I can get detailed profiles from folks, almost to their doorsteps. I love when I find "untraceable people", the ones that took proactive steps in managing their details on the web.

Comment: @brasofilo What can you find about me? (No need to post it here, ha ha)

Comment: @EdPlunkett Can the email on your SO profile be found anywhere else? It wouldn't be hard to build an email alias list.

Comment: a good example of why, Privacy Policy is not the place for jokey text.

Comment: @EdPlunkett - clearly you are Edward John Moreton Drax Plunkett, 18th Baron of Dunsany, and one of my favorite writers. I'm somewhat surprised to realize that this is you, seeing as how you have reputedly been dead for over 58 years, but mine is not to question. Now, sir, if it's not too much to ask, *please* drop all this foolish software stuff and get back to writing things like "The Fortress Unvanquishable, Save for Sacnoth". Thanks. :-)

Comment: @lolesque She's not that subtle. I've been with girls who did strange devious paranoia-inducing things like that. Different personality type.

Comment: @BobJarvis Oh, I've just been staying at [my club](http://www.sacred-texts.com/neu/dun/tawo/tawo20.htm).

Comment: Ah, well then - let's all go upstairs and have a drink with the members... :-)

Comment: Probably what happened is that the SO user you corresponded with via e-mail doesn't realize they're on a botnet.

Comment: I was contacted by recruiters because of my activity on SO in the past too (note that it’s all fine, I’m open to job offers and set my profile in that way); what some recruiters do when you decline is that they politely ask for suggestions on other people you think that could fit the job. So one possibility is that someone who had your email address and your name recommended you for it.

Comment: @lolesque Derp, "SO", I finally got your joke -- it just took a day to sink in.

Comment: Just had a similar thing happen to me. I was contacted by a "Mark Speranza" regarding "Android engineering opportunities at Facebook", at an email address I've never made public on my profile or blog. I got an email from him in June 2015, where he said he'd "stumbled upon my information on StackOverflow"; at the time, I replied, saying thanks, but relocation to the States was a dealbreaker for me (he knew I was Aussie). A second email today means spam in my book; he clearly never read my reply. If you feel like thanking him for spamming, his email is msperanza@fb.com (he won't mind, I'm sure).

Comment: Is your profile bio a quote from a book or something? If so, I would love to know which.

Comment: @hobbs No, it's just something that popped into my head.

Comment: If you use gravatar (or did so in the past), your email address is effectively public.

Comment: @brasofilo Any luck?

Comment: @Ed, jeje, normally it's easier to start from a social site, any of them... for what I scanned here at SO, no link to something with your details... checking US and Canadian GNW area, only 2 matches at Facebook and I'd go for the `.7` one. No solid lead at Linkedin. Also nothing with heavy filtering on Google (lots of scrappers).

Comment: What's the overall result here? How did the recruiter get the e-mail? Maybe you could update the post with the findings...

Comment: @DeerHunter She wouldn't tell me how she got it.

Comment: *Hey Ed! Love .Net and female empowerment? ;)*

Comment: @JonathonReinhart The exact words. Did you get the same email? Don't tell me they just call everybody Ed.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Lol no, mine was addressed to Jonathon.  I did indeed get the same email. I realized, after reading this post, that I had my email address visible on my GitHub profile, to which there is a link on my SO profile. Oops.

Comment: See also the [new preview about Terms of Service](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277369/preview-a-tos-update-restricting-companies-that-scrape-your-profile-information)

Comment: ...Which is now live.

Comment: fyi I also got a "job probe" from Carpetsmoker :(

Comment: Pardon my inquisitiveness, but why are web-scrapers a problem, really? Sure, I agree many are unsoliticated advertising companies and spammers trying to either hoax you into a product or service, others (the good guys) are simply scraping to build better business profiling for themselves and hence target their customers better. I seriously don't mind that - AS LONG AS I don't know about it. Yeah ignorance is bliss sometimes. But if that business then contacted me and offered a service - well if it's close to what I would be looking for - I may consider it. If it's totally left field get lost!

Comment: @EdPlunkett Upd3: Turn down for what!

Comment: Just a wild try a"*"ton"*"s@gmail.com was this the email adress? If yes I'll tell you how :)

Comment: @Petr Whois lookup?

Comment: @EdPlunkett yep whois lookup, you have few links on your stack profile where one leads to... ouch you just delete it right? :D

Comment: @Petr Sure did. You can send me a Christmas card though! FWIW though none of those links were there when I asked this question.

Comment: @EdPlunkett  Deal!

Comment: @Servy Note that Stack Exchange Inc isn't swearing an oath to tell the truth, the whole truth, and nothing but the truth when talking with you. Just because they say they couldn't imagine [at the time of writing] ever consider collecting...

Comment: @GeroldBroser Their privacy policy is in fact a contract, so they *are* in fact bound to tell the truth in this respect, and do have a legal obligation to not share your private information.  Now that's not to say they couldn't have violated their contract, just that unlike a recruiter there are consequences for them not telling the truth on a matter such as this.

Comment: @Servy Thx for the info. I wasn't fully aware of the legal implications. I just wanted to express that writing/speaking words and doing things are "two different pairs of shoes", as we say in my mother tongue.

Comment: Quote: "This was five years ago. I've since revised my judgement of Stack Exchange's ethics downward, roughly to zero." You seem to have added that, um, bombshell, yesterday ... and no-one seems to have asked you about it. Any chance you might elaborate? I'm genuinely interested!

Comment: What does *Stack Exchange's ethics downward, roughly to zero.* mean? is you want to measure ethics (at least for this post)? then was it a binary form? (1 was past, now it is close to 0) Or was it close to nothing?

Answer (score 295, accepted):

We're not handing out your information to *anyone*, and we log *all* access to it.

Some recruiters (especially those contingency ones) use some pretty elaborate user scripts that attempt to fetch as much data as they can from many sources (github, bitbucket, etc, etc) while they're viewing a profile on Stack Overflow. It didn't come from us, unfortunately we can't control what public fragments of information they're able to piece together about you.

We don't do that kinda crap. And I'll be *really* happy when Jobs is fully integrated because I'd love for us to set a much louder standard that clearly says *don't do that kinda crap, it only annoys people.*

You could reply with:

> I ... think .. I just need to be held right now. I've got Mookey the stuffed bear, but I'm not in a very good place.

I don't think they'll contact you subsequently.

#### RE: Your Update 2:

Classic contingency recruiting. They are *famous* for "share your friends with me and I'll kick you some cash if I can get them hired!" Deplorable, stupid and disgusting. And I'm not even going to get started.

I can't be positive because I'm not omnipotent, but I'm 99.9999999999974% sure that's how they got your information, and why they alluded to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thank you, Tim. That was my intuition about SO, which I ought to have confirmed by looking up the Privacy Policy before posting. But the more I google, the more I'm convinced those pieces of information just aren't out there in any connected way.

Comment: Addendum - it's okay if you have a stuffed bear named Mookey. And if you're not in a good place, it'll get better if you don't go to work for _that_ company.

Comment: @EdPlunkett They buy a lot of databases too - none of 'em from us, and I'm not sure if all of 'em are even legally for sale. I've gotten similar noise via email addresses I _know_ I've only shared with a few people. But then those people go on to allow some crap app to access all their contacts, and then it goes to market. It's just mind-boggling.

Comment: Hey, who knows? Maybe that's just what Mookey and I need!

Comment: @EdPlunkett Think of Mookey. Make Mookey proud.

Comment: Mookey is telling me to do terrible things. [Terrible, terrible things...](http://www.michaelowencarroll.com/hh/s049.htm)

Comment: I think I need to write an open letter to recruiters.

Comment: I bet you'd get the same results if you wrote an open letter to your salad.

Comment: If someone has their private info posted somewhere on the Interwebs, I'll find it and I'll use it. Amazingly, only a small percentage asks *"How did you find my mobile number?"*

Comment: @EdPlunkett don't be surprised if the [salad](http://sopython.com/salad/) answers ...

Comment: @rene, *Laurel*

Comment: I've actually responded to the more persistent and annoying recruiters with `Does your client allow on-fire monkey pets in the workplace?` or something to that effect. That gets the job done.

Comment: @Qix Or I could say the terms of my parole forbid me from interviewing anywhere within 500 yards of a school, a liquor store, or a petting zoo.

Comment: I think @EdPlunkett wins this one.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Just to add to Tim's response.  There are a host of companies like Entelo and Gild that provide this information to recruiters.  They're very sophisticated in that they scrape content from many sources (SO being a big one) and find contact information in other places (your blog?  a comment you wrote on disqus one time?) and combine all these disparate sources into a "composite profile" that they then sell to recruiters.  We are in the process of making this as difficult as possible for them to obtain anything from us even via scraping.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I prefer to have certain recruiters think I'm just incredibly insane. US laws don't favor talking about criminal records, even in joke form, in regards to employment. D:

Comment: @EdPlunkett - it's not what Mookey tells you...it's what he *doesn't* tell you...

Comment: Is it just me who finds `99.9999999999974%` to be an awkward number? Sorry for being dumb, but is there some pun in it?

Comment: @CoolGuy Would you have preferred [99.9...%](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.999...)?

Comment: @TimPost I'm just curious as to why this was allowed in the first place? Using an elaborate script to gather information on users (I understand it's been taken care of) is kind of a big deal, if you allowed a script to crawl someone's information and get into contact with us regarding that information, that's kind of a big deal.. Basically what I'm hearing is that I could write a script to crawl every single user in your database (or download it) and then sell all this information off for my own personal gain.. I'm not sure if I'm alone, but I don't like that at all..

Comment: @13aal It wasn't allowed, it just wasn't specifically disallowed, so they did it anyway.

Comment: So if a legitimate recruitier (someone reputable and known to be a real recruiter), contacts you and says they've found you on StackOverFlow, and hey who knows - they could be offering you the job of the century! An opportunity should always be looked at, at face value. Besides, I may have shared my SOF posts elsewhere (facebook, linkedin, etc) and so yeah it's quite easy to put 2-and-2 together.

Comment: @Fernando68 I can't discount that this sometimes _does_ happen; a really good recruiter is able to follow the wake of awesomeness someone left, manages to catch up to them, and talks to them on their level with a really good offer. It's the other 98.7774% of interactions that get me a bit depressed :)

Answer (score 179):

As Tim wrote in his [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/318622/4), the worst offenders are combining profiles from different places, scraping GitHub, Stack Overflow, LinkedIn, etc., sometimes guessing email addresses. Some companies are even doing this as a business model.

There are a couple of things we can do from a technical perspective, but the first thing we're going to do is change the TOS ASAP, so that at least this is a violation of the Stack Overflow terms of service. At least that will give us some recourse against anyone who does this openly. Watch for an announcement in the next few days.

Comment: Glad to hear it, and glad to hear you guys aren't taking this sort of thing lightly. If there's any way for you to link the name "Mark Speranza" or the email address "msperanza@fb.com" to an SO account, please add him to the list of unsolicited spammers. Happy to forward the emails in question to an SO moderator.

Comment: [status-almost-completed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277369/preview-a-minor-tos-update-restricting-companies-that-scrape-your-profile-infor)

Comment: What can a user to to protect self from such data mining? Is a profile "safer" when Twitter and GitHub aren't linked? What about location, company and title? Does the free text area matter much?

Comment: Don't use mobile phones for 2FA.
Never use the same mobile phone number for 2FA for more than one site.
Passwords go without saying.  But if they can link all your accounts and get password recovery......  Facebook is careless but others could be malicious.

Answer (score 79):

I suggest posting the e-mail publicly, with full headers (just remove your own e-mail address and possibly server).

That will help the rest of the world write spam filters, which will in turn incentivize recruiters to be less spammy and not get tagged as undesirable.  Moreover, it'll make their details publicly available where they can be scraped for inclusion in unsavory lists (I would never suggest that a Stack Exchange user do the unsavory things, but just putting the recruiter's email in plain text ought to bring it to the attention to those who are going to do unkind things anyway)

In addition, since they're lying about where they got the information, the email qualifies as "deceptive" and you can file a complaint with the FTC about a CAN-SPAM violation.  See https://www.consumer.ftc.gov/articles/0038-spam#report

Comment: Food for thought.

Answer (score 21):

Just pitching my own personal solution to this particular problem. I register to each service (especially ones I don't 100% trust) with a different email address. I either use my domain `some.service@madara.ninja`, or, in the case of gmail, you can do something like this: `my.real.email+some.service@gmail.com`, you will still get the mail at `my.real.email@gmail.com`, but the `+some.service` part will be visible.

That way, you can know exactly where the email they have is from.

I know it's not a solution in the sense that fragments of your data is public, but this at least gives you some sort of indication.

Comment: I prefer disposable email service like one offered by hidemyass.

Comment: I've ran into almost 100% rejection with the "+" trick. The field validator doesn't think it's a valid character in an email address (or they purposefully reject it for the aliasing reason).

Comment: I agree with @ChrisFannin this would be good, but sadly it only works on websites that are in the more trustworthy bucket, where you wouldn't really need this anyway. The problematic ones don't have the talent/will to handle valid emails: I've run into 2 sites where the `.` in `my.name@gmail.com` was deemed invalid and an inquiry about it resulted in an explicit rejection ("working as intended") from the support person after I quoted the [RFC standard from 1982](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc822#section-6.1). Imagine what their response would be to `+`.

Comment: @TWiStErRob Like I said, I use my own domain to have emails like `stackoverflow@madara.ninja`, those usually get accepted more.

Comment: Aaah, I see, so you don't use the `+` trick, that's neat, sorry from not noticing that. Sadly for gmail (and others) I think a harmful agent could just strip anything between `+...@`.

Comment: @TWiStErRob: They rarely bother (I've had emails sent to trolling addresses like `you.yes.you.stop.sending.me.spam@madara.ninja`, a normal human being would clearly think it to be a fake email (although, it isn't :D).

Comment: "+" part is easily removed. Useful only for the most dumb automatic spams.

Comment: On the plus side, a bot shouldn't be able to, say, use a compromised GitHub account `my.email+github@gmail.com` to attack a Stack Overflow account associated with `my.email+stackoverflow@gmail.com`.

Comment: @watarok why not?  If I wrote a bot which removed `+github`, I'd certainly try adding `+stackoverflow` `+reddit` and probably several thousands more...

Comment: @watarok What you could do is use salted hash of the service name/domain for the plus part. I know, not even funny anymore.

Comment: This works. One better to use at two least email addresses. One for social activity and one for very personal use, with personal I mean single business/work exchanges.

Comment: Been doing this a lot recently, then I forgot details for somewhere and had to remember what I typed after the + just to get a recovery email.

Comment: @weston That's why you use a password manager. I like LastPass.

Comment: Thanks, yes I did start using one after that actually

Comment: It works for me also. It would be much convenience to use a different email addresses between public, private and personal activities.

Comment: @AloisMahdal Indeed, those were meant only as examples. I would not simply use the plaintext of the domain.

Comment: This is the proper way to avoid spammers. Create profiles SPECIFIC to what YOU are after. Don't use the same email address,password across different systems. Systems do compare details and try out passwords that you've entered into one, to see if they can get into your accounts elsewhere. Just use common sense with your privacy

Comment: I'm doing this since years ago... and it is useful and surprising. I've got spam from address I share with a big newspaper ("La Nación") and an ice cream big company ("Sandro"), both from here (Argentina).

Comment: I use a similar scheme for sites I don't know/trust - but it involves more work to set up: I make a randomly-generated email alias (eph7hocu@example.net) that forwards to tricky-stackoverflow@example.net, that forwards to tricky@example.net. That way, in a compromise situation: 1) The randomised alias can easily be replaced. 2) Spam going to the old address simply gets rejected. 3) Spammers can't just truncate the "+alias" part. 4) It is easy to look up what disused aliases are/were for. 5) I can set my mail filters to be based on the *to* field rather than subject line/sender/etc

Answer (score 14):

I just reply with a link to my 5gb "resume" that happens to be MPAA protected content.

Comment: Haha, `Reply: I can't read this.`