# Address ONLY used for SO account receiving programming related spam

Tags: support, spam, email, privacy

> **Author's Note:** There are a couple of similar *questions*, but in both cases the *answers* cannot apply here.
>
> 1. This question not a duplicate of: [Is my email address accessible?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/293532/is-my-email-address-accessible)
>      The answer given there: *"The recruiter must have got your e-mail from somewhere else"* doesn't apply in this case.
> 2. This question not a duplicate of: [Recruiter claims to have gotten my email address from Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318621)
>      The accepted answer in that case was that *"the recruited was given the email by a (human) third party that the OP had corresponded with."*  That does not apply in my case.
>
> The situation described in that post was different.  Specifically that questioner had given the email to at least 1 third party, and the discussion focussed around the fact the third party presumably passed it on.  I hadn't given the email to *anyone* else, and the information people offered here about the gravatar hash seems to be the only plausible explanation.  My opinion is that questions that have different answers must be different questions.  However the closure is probably unimportant now: I think this question has probably garnered as much helpful information from the mods and staff (and others) as is possible.

Is it possible for any third party to obtain my email address used to register for SO?  I ask because I've today started receiving spam emails, coding related, sent to that address.  However the address isn't used for any other purpose.

Details:
When registering with any site or company I use a unique email address of the form company_name@example.com.  All email sent to anything_at_all@example.com redirects to my real email by default, unless I specifically block individual addresses.  When I registered here I used overflow@example.com.  My sign-up on here was using email and password, not using one of the third party logins such as google or facebook.  overflow@example.com has never been used elsewhere.

I've never corresponded with anyone on here using it (I can't even send from the address).  I've never signed up elsewhere with that address.  I don't use any sites linked to SO, such as the careers.

As far as I can see that address is only stored by SO, and on my email system.  My email is stored locally, and only remains on my ISP's server for a few days.  The last legitimate email I have from SO was in Feb 2013.  I've previously received 2 sign-up emails, 1 from SO regarding the careers site and 2 when I reset my password.

*Could the email have been harvested from my email system?*  It seems unlikely, since even if I had a security problem on my local computer, it would be remarkable that only that one email address, last used 3 years ago, was the only one targeted.  And further that some scammer linked the address to SO, and sent coding related spam.  In my experience coding related spam is rare: more often it's helpful people warning me about a problem with my bank account.

*Could the address have been harvested from some intermediate server which handled a previous email sent to me at overflow@example.com?*  Same answer really: I couldn't answer technically, but finding a 3-year old address and sending *appropriate* spams to it seems surprising.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker: possibly, but again the accepted answer doesn't apply.  In the question you link, the answer was that the recruiter got the email from a (human) third party that the OP had corresponded with using their SO email address.  Unless I've had a major brain fart, this email address exists nowhere outside SO and my local email store.

Comment: So you have a specific `overflow@yourdomain.com` and have started receiving coding-related E-Mail exactly to that address recently? Might be worth taking up with `team@stackoverflow.com`

Comment: Only staff/moderators have access to a user's email and neither would (or are allowed to) disclose that to anyone. Could it be that someone got hold of your naming convention (maybe on a mailing list for another site/social network), put it together with a couple of other bits of info (googled your name - found your domain etc.. etc..) and then just look a punt?

Comment: It is a bit unfortunate but you might have fallen into the trap called Gravatar email hash as your account on [PPCG](http://data.stackexchange.com/codegolf/query/459485) seems to have that associated to your account and Gravatar had (or has)  a known security flaw: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21117/is-using-gravatar-a-security-risk

Comment: I'd Google for that E-Mail address with `site:stackoverflow.com` just to exclude the possibility it's there after all somewhere, in a piece of code or something

Comment: @Pekka웃 wouldn't googling that emailaddress not make things worse? Or do you trust Google, Inc?

Comment: @Pekka웃 I tried searching - duckduckgo: no results for email.  google: some random results for the words "my" "domain" and "overflow", nothing related to the email, or me.  rene: i know searching potentially puts the email out there, but it's no big deal as I'll change my SO address and block the old one if I have further problems.

Comment: @Pekka웃: do you mean to just email team@... ?

Comment: @Stuart yeah - this kind of case definitely warrants contacting them directly. They'll likely respond to this here, too, though, in due time.

Comment: @JonClements: It's almost impossible to rule out some sort of guesswork.  However googling my name doesn't return that domain.  The domain isn't the one I use for my real email;  nor is it one I put websites on.  I have another domain I use for temporary/in-development sites.  I couldn't swear I've never used the domain for anything else (I've used this system and these domains for many years), but it's generally just for incoming email.  Such guesswork just seems rather low-volume for spammers.

Comment: I would change the title so it becomes clear it's not a case like the one in the duplicate. Perhaps something like `Address I created specifically for SO account receiving programming related spam`

Comment: @rene prior to their turning into Skynet in 2023, there is no record of Google being untrustworthy with privacy around search queries. *Oh no I've revealed too much, please forget this right away*

Comment: @Stuart Well... after a couple of minutes of looking around - I was able to get your domain name easily enough. I think I can see how the "overflow" part was gathered, but heck - it's still at best a wild guess and a lot of cross-referencing and can't see how the heck automated scrapers would put that together...For one email address, I can't see anyone bothering with the effort - in fact - I've lost interest now - although still fairly curious :p

Comment: @JonClements: indeed it's not impossible to put it together, although it would require quite some guess as to the system I use - and that I registered with overflow@ not stackoverflow@ which would be more normal for me (must have been feeling lazy that day).  However it (a) seems a lot of work and (b) is odd that I've only got spam to overflow@.  I'd expect paypal@ and mybankname@ etc would be more obvious targets.

Comment: Judging from [this meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/277369/144883), they are getting a lot of complaints about this.  Where there is smoke there is usually a fire.  A ToS doesn't mean a toss to people that do this, it has no teeth.

Comment: @HansPassant: the email shouldn't have been scraped from my profile as it's not publicly visible - AFAIK only visible to mods and staff.  According the the answer [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149636/who-can-see-what-in-my-profile/149637#149637) for a mod to see someone's email they need to click an extra link and that action is logged.  So even if someone got hold of a moderator's login and scraped all the info it would show up easily in the logs.

Comment: Other than today there are no entries in the audit log for moderators accessing your PII.

Comment: It's worth adding that depending on where you live the person sending those emails might have a case in law to answer, even if they "bought" your email address in good faith but didn't perform due diligence.

Comment: @Pekka웃: Yeah, no record anyone can *find* anyway.

Comment: Aren't there any white hats around that we could ask to try and reveal any private credentials from the system? I don't know how much work each guessed e-mail address is worth, but if these issues keep popping up, the reasonable guess is that getting these e-mail addresses is simpler than we anticipate it (i.e. not actually impossible), rather than each being the result of individual guesswork.

Comment: Have you checked out your MTA logs for attempts of guessing and/or that mail header to see from where it came from (ie. wasn't a forward from someone else).

Comment: @Braiam: I don't have MTA logs - the domain doesn't link to any server of mine, just an email forwarder.  However ANY email ...@mydomain.com will forward to me, except half a dozen (sales@, office@) I have blocked.  No other emails have been guessed/attempted for many months, possibly years.  That's what made me curious - it seems targeted as if someone knows that email is associated with SO.    Looking at the email headers both came from Amazon SES to my forwarder, and then to my real email.

Answer (score 24):

Moderators and employees are forbidden to share any of your information. They refrain from doing so not so much it's because that's the rule, but because they're great people that hate recruiter spam too :)

We log all access to personally-identifying information. <strike>No one, employee or moderator, has viewed your email address prior to me to the time you posted this, which happened right now.</strike> A few mods saw this after you posted it, and double checked. <sup>[comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319776/address-only-used-for-so-account-receiving-programming-related-spam#comment327188_319839)</sup>  So let's say the data warehouse knows your name, and maybe:

- They bought a list of customers from a domain registrar, found your domain, and guessed at emails. Companies have invested *tons* of money in software that does these sorts of correlations from many, many sources.
- They bought a list of customers from a hosting company, and did something similar
- (From comments) They were able to find your avatar hash in a rainbow table, or noticed they didn't have it and put a GPU farm to work.

And by 'bought' I mean obtained with the presumption of no wrongdoing, because I'm a nice person and try to assume the best in folks.

I can say with 100% certainty that it did *not* come from us. This is one of the biggest reasons why we're very aggressively working to block these types of creepy crawlers - we can't have bad actors out there making people wonder if they misplaced their trust by giving it to us.

The weirder (and kinda creepier) scenario here is actually the simplest explanation - this is becoming much too common. You'll be hearing me saying some not-so-nice things about these outfits in the near future.

Comment: Before I looked up the definition I was wondering what sets of clothing you were talking about and why you would talk about them negatively.

Comment: I would never talk trash about my leisure suits. Never.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Tim.  It's certainly possible someone got the domain and then tried guessing stuff.  However they can't be banging out random emails, because anything_at_all@mydomain.com will reach me except for half a dozen I have blocked.  Possibly the gravatar issue is an explanation there: if someone tried every domain in existence against a list of gravatar hashes.

Comment: @TimPost - one thing I'm curious about: you say no-one accessed my email before you?  However Flexo strongly implied that moderators had accessed it yesterday in response to my question (quite understandably)

Comment: @StuartWhitehouse Rainbow tables do exist for those, I've never been shopping for them so I don't know how extensive they might be - but that could very well explain it. If it can help piece you together online, they'll pay top-dollar for it.

Comment: @StuartWhitehouse I just noticed that too. Access to PII is logged in a history table, which also shows the history of changes to email addresses. But, access to that history table is also logged on our end. Prior to yesterday, no one looked at your email directly, or that history table; I just emailed one of our engineering managers to make it so you can't see the emails in the history table, as having that access logged in two places is as undesirable as it is inconvenient for audit purposes. Still, I'm certain no one looked at it until you raised this concern.

Comment: I guess the final situation is we'll never know.  The gravatar issue might be involved, but it must also have involved some curiously targeted guesswork.  I've changed both my personal email on SO and notification one, although it seems I can't change my login email.  Incidentally does anyone know how to ensure my updated email hash can't be visible via the gravatar issue?

Comment: @StuartWhitehouse Use a custom avatar, or an identicon. Gravatar goes by MD5, so it's always visible as the target in an `<img>` tag.

Comment: @StuartWhitehouse We'll never know _positively_, but matching the gravatar md5 in a rainbow table is the most plausible explanation. These companies make a lot of money assembling a complete portfolio about you, complete with contact info, which they sell for a lot of money to recruiters. It's awful, disgusting and as bottom-feeding as you can get - we're actively working to better protect everyone.

Comment: I'm not sure the complete email would appear in a rainbow table as the "mydomain" isn't actually 2 words, but 1 word and 2 characters.  However someone could have done a brute force test of possible emails against a list of known hashes.

Comment: @StuartWhitehouse That's how they do it. You grab all the lists of all the known hashes you can find, join with your lists of hashes, see what's known, and then put the GPU farm to work on the rest. It's a business model, just like the company calling you about a phone bill debt of $16 from 30 years ago that they bought for pennies on the dollar. Disgusting in every sense of the word.

Comment: It's so awesome that you guys respond to support questions on an _Easter Sunday_ - I wish other companies did that :-)

Comment: @JonasCz I don't mean to set precedence :) Many of us use our sites for our off-time stuff too. I've delighted in checking to see what's up on Meta during my spare time for the last six plus years .. I guess some things never change :) The company is pretty firm in its request that we do non-work stuff on weekends and holidays; it's just that for many of us, this was our non-work stuff prior to being hired.

Comment: This is actually really reassuring to hear that SO is defending my information from getting to unauthorized people. @TimPost I hope you guys realise just HOW valueable the big data is that you guys are sitting on. Datamongers must be salivating of what y'all could do with the stuff you could gather if you had less moral concerns.

Comment: @Magisch [we do](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277369/preview-a-tos-update-restricting-companies-that-scrape-your-profile-information). You'll very likely see me object and fight against this like Gordon Ramsay would object to rotten fish in the coming weeks. I'm at the point where I'm running out of the ability to be civil now. It makes me that angry. We're not a commodity to be sold, we're f\*\*king people and I will fully use my position to advocate that. F\*\*king rubbish is what it is.

Comment: @TimPost Yes, I can relate. I don't know why these corps are doing it either, because unsolicited low quality ads are the fastest express path to get me to never buy a product or consider working for a company ever in the future again.

Comment: @TimPost I don't mean to add more anger and frustration and I really appreciate how you take action when you notice PII is leaked into a log table but I don't hear you address the possible [gravatar route](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/79856/158100) at a larger scale. If we assume the worst case scenario, shouldn't you consider all accounts that have a gravatar profile image now being compromised and with that use your powers to inform the users but also slam the door shut on that Gravatar route?

Comment: @rene We did address this some time ago by allowing avatar uploads, with identicon being the default (depending on what we could guess that you might want depending on how you signed up). We're running some numbers now on how many are still using it, when I get some more details, I plan to open another discussion. A few conversations need to happen internally first, but I hate the idea of it making things easier for companies to stalk our users like this.