# Is my email address visible to the other party in the Job "messages"?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs, privacy, jobs-messages

Is my email address visible to the other party which I sent an enquiry about a job? (I don't like my email address being collected).

[image]

p.s: I read this question [Is my email address accessible?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/293532/is-my-email-address-accessible) but I don't know if that answer includes the "jobs" section as well (maybe the answer is older than jobs release).

**UPDATE:** So far (no answer yet, so i just speculate) this does not look so good. I got a reply from the recruiter and i could see his email in his reply like mine is showing in the screenshot i posted.
Well, if he could see mine too, that would be **a major privacy issue** and could cause trouble to people (Fancy contacting the reqruiter with an inappropriate email address).

Comment: _"could cause trouble to people (Fancy contacting the reqruiter with an inappropriate email address)"_ If you're using an inappropriate email address for anything, including talking to a recruiter, then you caused trouble to yourself.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition i can't tell if you have understood the problem here. The situation is that the system exposes the email you used to signup in stackoverflow, in a business context; while talking to a recruiter. When a user signed-up in stackoverflow years ago using a whatever inappropriate-or-not email, he didnt knew that particular email would be exposed without his consent in a business contact.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I understood the problem. On the other hand, it appears that you did not understand my comment. :)

Answer (score 6):

Yes, if you send a question to a recruiter then your email address is visible to them. Our [privacy policy](https://stackexchange.com/legal/privacy-policy) mentions that we do this for job applications, but it neglects to mention this case.

I've embedded an image here because we don't currently have fragments for the privacy policy :(

[image: Privacy Policy]

The basis of this is that initiating contact with an employer is implicit consent for them to reply to you which currently involves exposing your contact information.

The policy was intended to cover anytime you contact an employer or agree to be contacted by one, but it no longer speaks to one way that could happen. I'll ask our community/legal teams to update it appropriately. *Or* maybe we shouldn't be exposing your contact information in this case. It's always worked this way, but I'll bring that up with the team and see what the consensus is.

Comment: If i apply directly or if i give consent (the two options you are reffering to) then i guess its okay. But if i just ask for some more details on a job (my specific case) then i would prefer not to share my information untill im convinced its a job im interested in and/or its legit. So i should be able to talk unanimously with the recruiter for clarifications. In my specific case, my email got exposed without giving me a chance to make up my mind if im interested or not. well no harm done but i think the system's broken there.

Comment: @Sharky we're discussing this further and it's likely that we'll either not give out your contact details for this specific case or make it clear that, that will happen so you can make an informed decision.

Comment: just a thought: you may want to inform the user which exactly is the email you are going to expose. since its about business, better make it clear. someone may have forgotten the email he used to register and would really prefer `myname@mysurname.com` over `noobKiller666@some-gaming-clan.com`

Comment: Fragments? You mean anchors?

Comment: @DeanWard I would suggest that you turn of the email showing on that place, because you might get into legal trouble, until its legal page is updated

Comment: @BoundaryImposition Fragments is a valid name for it: http://www.w3.org/Addressing/URL/4_2_Fragments.html (In the URL, not the document)

Comment: @Anders: Nice! :)]

Comment: hello Dean, has this issue been fixed?